# Glitch in topojson.merge

Tags: d3.js, topojson

Any idea of why this glitch happens when using topojson.merge?

[image]

```
svg.append('path')
.datum(topojson.merge(BR, BR.objects.mg.geometries.filter(function(d) {
  if (d.properties.geocode === '3136306' || d.properties.geocode === '3109402' ) {
    return true;
  }
})))
.attr('class', 'fmg')
.attr('d', path);
```

[EDIT]

I've painted in blue the area that I was hoping to get from the merge.

[image]

Comment: what are the respective areas for `d.properties.geocode === '3136306'` and `d.properties.geocode === '3109402'`

Comment: @paradite I've painted in blue the area that I was hoping to get from the merge.